# MIPS: search for a certain word in inside a text file

Tags: mips

I need to search if a particular word is stored inside an external text file. I tried to store what's in the file (not much data anyway) in a buffer and then compare with the text word (given by the user) via

```
    lb $t3, buffer
lb $t0, stringname($t5)

beqz $t3, check2
beqz $t0, missmatch
slt $t7, $t0, $t3
```

as already seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698217/mips-compare-input-string-to-one-stored-in-memory) on SO. But, while this works for two simple strings inserted by the user, it doesn't now.
I'm not here to ask code and homework done but at least some ideas, since mine are running low. Thanks

Comment: Since you've given us only a part of your code and said that whether your code works or not depends on the circumstances, it seems difficult to actually find a reason.

Comment: @user35443 you're right. I am going to provide complete code when I'll be at home